# webgl bufferdata and enableVertexAttribute funcs take a lot of time

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl

I draw 3d obj with webgl and use a shader program draw for it. And I draw other things on 3d obj as 2d dimension.

But when I open page, fps is down. I look at performance from chrome developers tool and I see in 3d obj rendering bufferdata and enableVertexAttribute funcs take about 11 ms but in 2d obj rendering it takes about 0 and 1 ms . Its happen when I render 2d obj otherwise it works nice.

Why there is huge difference between them and how I fixed this ?

Comment: Are you calling `bufferData` in your render loop? In general buffer data is an init time only thing

Comment: Yes I do,  in some situation. In render loop I use buffer data if new obj is necessary. But if create before and need in frame I use already created obj.